# How can I get the pid by its executable path in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

In Windows, how can I get the process ID of a program, provided its absolute EXE file path?

Comment: Note that there can easily be several processes running the same program, so be ready to accept 0, 1, or more PIDs.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate (after more than 13 years)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How can I get the process ID of a program from its absolute file path?

Something like the following:

```
wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath | findstr /c:"C:\apps\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
C:\apps\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe 6272
```

where `6272` is the Process ID.

As [Andreas](https://superuser.com/users/727393/andreas) has pointed out in a comment:

> *"The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is **deprecated** as of Windows 10, version 21H1, and as of the 21H1 semi-annual channel release of Windows Server. This utility is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI (see Chapter 7—Working with WMI)."* ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic))

You can of course use PowerShell instead:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name='notepad++.exe'" | Select-Object ExecutablePath, ProcessId | format-list

ExecutablePath : C:\apps\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
ProcessId      : 6272
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [WMIC - Windows Management - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)

Comment: _"The WMI command-line (WMIC) utility is **deprecated** as of Windows 10, version 21H1, and as of the 21H1 semi-annual channel release of Windows Server. This utility is superseded by Windows PowerShell for WMI (see Chapter 7—Working with WMI)."_ ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic))

Comment: @Andreas Answer updated